# Python UDF for Pig in Azure Data Factory On demand HDInsight cluster

Tags: python, azure, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

How to include python UDF for pig when using Azure data factory and azure blob to store the pig script?

Comment: Please make sure you are asking the right question (and perhaps add an example of what you tried). -- Currently you ask how to store a pig script which is probably not what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

@abu,

I recommend you can refer to the official document to konw how to use Pig and Python On Azure HDinsight.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-python/
If you store your pig script into Azure storage, pleaes try to use `WASB:// path` to load your files.